# Images in IE8 are squeezed

Tags: css, image

I'm having an issue in IE8 and below.
http://www.wdcga.org/tournaments/keefer.php
I'm adding the pictures and keeping the width and height.
What's the best solution?

Comment: Which images? The ones above "about our sponsor"?

Answer (score 4):

Your 1st image is of dimensions `93px * 150px`

On your img element you have specified:

```
width="100px" height="150px"
```

Therefore its going to distort your image (stretch) to fit within these dimensions

---

The 2nd has a width of 106px, so this would be squashed/squeezed/distorted to fit.

---

Remove `width` attribute from your images and these will no longer be distorted.

---

Also you have the following in your CSS which will affect things:

```
img, embed, object, video {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

You can either remove this (which will fix the problem), or, as I don't know what else this is for, override it inline:

```
<img style="max-width:auto;"..
```

Comment: Well this fixed it in IE, now it's an issue in Chrome ;-(  Not sure I'm really understanding this.  Is it best to just put my photos back in with the correct height and width?

Comment: I'm using the max-width 100% for responsive images.